# Prove $x^2 - x + 1 $ is always positive.

Tags: inequality, quadratics

While solving a question, I came up with an inequality : $(1+x)(1-x+x^2)>0$

The book stated -

> where $(1-x+x^2)$ is always positive as $D<0$ and $a>0$

I'm not that sure how did it conclude that it will be always positive just with the two results ( $ D < 0 \ \& \ a > 0 $ ) .

I know that the Discriminant of the quadratic equation is negative. But how do we conclude that the quadratic equation (given) will always be positive?

Comment: Complete the square to see what's going on.

Comment: Got it! Silly question. Thanks a lot, it rarely strikes my mind. $(x-\frac{1}{2})^2 + \frac{3}{4} $ .. is always positive. Cool, thanks a lot!

Comment: $D < 0$ means that there are no real roots (hence the polynomial never changes signs), whereas $a > 0$ means that $\lim_{x \to \infty} p(x) = +\infty > 0$.

Comment: Awesome, it's exactly I was looking for. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As another answer tells you, you can see that the polynomial is always positive by completing the square.

Another way to see this is to note that the discriminant is negative. The discriminant for a quadratic polynomial $ax^2 + bx + c$ is $D = b^4-4ac$. It is a fact that the graph of $y =ax^2 +bx + c$ crosses (or touches) the $x$-axis is $D \geq 0$. So since for your polynomial $D = (-1)^2 - 4 = -3 < 0$, the graph stays entirely on one side of the $x$-axis. Since $a>0$ you have the graph is *above* the $x$-axis, that is, the polynomial is always positive.

Comment: Oh! I see how it goes. Awesome! Thanks a lot Mr. Thomas.

Comment: I was just going through this answer again, @Thomas . There seems to be a typo, if I'm not wrong, in the formula for discriminant that you stated in your answer. $ D = \color{blue}{b^4} - 4ac$ ... there is the mistake.

Answer (score 7):

Note that $$x^2-x+1=\left(x-\frac 12\right)^2+\frac 34.$$

Comment: Yep! Got it. Thanks again, I don't know... completing the square method just doesn't strike my mind at a first glance on the question. :/

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, let $f(x) = x^2 - x + 1 \Rightarrow f'(x) = 2x-1 = 0 \iff x = 1/2$, and $1/2$ is the only critical point of $f$. Then $f''(1/2) = 2 > 0$, and this shows $f$ attains an absolute minimum at $x = 1/2$ which is $f(1/2) = 3/4$. This means $f(x) \geq 3/4 > 0 \Rightarrow f(x) > 0, \forall x$.